# Ionic 4 fingerprint aio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, fingerprint

Im using ionic 4 with angular to make an ionic fingerprint app. im using the example code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio. And followed all the steps. When i command out the constructor and following code the code is running when i will settup the entire code i will get a white screen with the following error:

consolelogs.js:49 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:92
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/index.js (index.js:141)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/home/home.page.ts (home-home-module.js:84)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/home/home.module.ts (home-home-module.js:30)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:84)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {



constructor(private faio: FingerprintAIO) { }

logging(){
this.faio.show({
    clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo', //Android: Used for encryption. iOS: used for dialogue if no `localizedReason` is given.
    clientSecret: 'o7aoOMYUbyxaD23oFAnJ', //Necessary for Android encrpytion of keys. Use random secret key.
    disableBackup:true,  //Only for Android(optional)
    localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin', //Only for iOS
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate' //Only for iOS
})
.then((result: any) => console.log(result))
}
}
```

I hope anyone can help me fix the error, Because i dont understand why im getting the errror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities here.

First is the issue is on your import, most likely it is the one causing the error, change your import to the code below OR

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';"
```

It's either you have not imported the plugin on your app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem came from your import , try this  :

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';
```